# Disadvantages of Async & Await - NodeJs

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm trying to move from callback to async/await. I know async/await is easy to use, readable, less code and can avoid callback hell. But, What are the disadvantages like performance wise?

Comment: I don't know of any disadvantages of `async/await`.  It's just a cleaner way to write asynchronous code.  If you're switching from plain callbacks, then there are hundreds of advantages to moving to promises in general (related to control flow and error handling) and then `async/await` is just extra syntax help on top of promises to make code easier to write.  But, the biggest move is first moving to promises over plain async callbacks.

Comment: Here's the only disadvantage I can think of.  Code written with `async/await` won't run in older environments (older browsers, older version of node.js) unless you transpile it first.  You can't polyfill new language syntax like this.  You would have to transpile.  Plain callback code can run in older versions of the engine.  And, even promise code written without `async/await` can be polyfilled to run in older versions.

Comment: FYI, I'm not sure there really is an answer to this question that will satisify anyone.

Comment: I would also add that Promises add additional overhead to your function, consuming more memory than callbacks.

Comment: Also, it's something new to learn how to use properly.  I see lots of newbies trying to `await` things that don't return a promise and then wondering why it doesn't work the way they want it to.

Comment: Consumes more memory. Hmmm.
Thanks @aiyan

Comment: @ShayamThomas - I rolled my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 2):

If what you're comparing is plain asynchronous callbacks to using promises with `await`, there really aren't very many disadvantages.  Promises by themselves are just a better way to code asynchronous operations than plain callbacks and promises with `await` are generally simpler to write than even just plain promises.

So, if I had to scratch the bottom of the barrel to try to list some disadvantages, this is all I can come up with:

1. `async/await` won't run in older environments (older browsers, older versions of node.js) unless you transpile it first. You can't polyfill new language syntax like this. You would have to transpile. Plain callback code can run in older versions of the engine. And, even promise code written without `async/await` can be polyfilled to run in older versions.
2. It's something new to learn how to use properly. I see lots of newbies trying to `await` things that don't return a promise and then wondering why it doesn't work the way they want it to.
3. Promises create an extra promise object for the engine and garbage collector to manage compared to a plain asynchronous callback.  Benchmarks others have shown don't show any meaningful difference in performance. These promise objects are small and the JS interpreter has been pretty well optimized for dealing with lots of small objects (as that's what it does all the time).

---

There are so many advantages to using promises and `async/await` that I've never run into a situation or heard of anyone running into a situation where the extra promise object that the engine creates was significant or relevant.  You get a lot of bang for your buck there with all the advantages of using promises to control the flow and sequencing of asynchronous operations and to propagate errors as desired.

Answer (score -1):

this is a more modern and elegant way of handling of unknown timing situations.one of the big difference or benefit between traditional callback and this modern way is its easy to maintain. its clean and readable.

below I write an example. if you see having to continually nest one level deeper and one level deeper for each action is not desirable. it a nightmare to be nested this many layers deep.

```js
// tradiatonal callback
eatBreakfast(function(){
  eatLunch(function(){
    eatDinner()
  })
})

// functions

function eatBreakfast(callback) {
  console.log("The eatBreakfast function started executing.")
  setTimeout(function() {
    addText("You just ate breakfast.")
    if (callback) callback()
  }, 800)
}

function eatLunch(callback) {
  console.log("The eatLunch function started executing.")
  setTimeout(function() {
    addText("You just ate lunch.")
    if (callback) callback()
  }, 300)
}

function eatDinner(callback) {
  console.log("The eatDinner function started executing.")
  setTimeout(function() {
    addText("You just ate dinner.")
    if (callback) callback()
  }, 600)
}
```

here this is modern way of handling this situation. one of the big benefits of using promises is that you do not need to keep nesting one level deeper for each event. its easier to understand or manage the infinitely nested callback approach.

```js
// 1
eatBreakfast().then(function(){
  return eatLunch()
}).then(function(){
  eatDinner()
})

// 2 => even easier to look with arrow functions
eatBreakfast()
.then(() => eatLunch())
.then(() => eatDinner())

//3 => even more clear way by this magical await word.
async function runOurActions() {
  await eatBreakfast()
  await eatLunch()
  await eatDinner()
}

// 4 => add error handling
async function runOurActions() {
  try {
    await eatBreakfast()
    await eatLunch()
    await eatDinner()
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}



// functions return promises
function eatBreakfast() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("The eatBreakfast function started executing.")
    setTimeout(function() {
      addText("You just ate breakfast.")
      resolve()
    }, 800)
  })
}

function eatLunch() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("The eatLunch function started executing.")
    setTimeout(function() {
      addText("You just ate lunch.")
      resolve()
    }, 300)
  })
}

function eatDinner() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    console.log("The eatDinner function started executing.")
    setTimeout(function() {
      addText("You just ate dinner.")
      resolve()
    }, 600)
  })
}
```